# Update multiple rows at once Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have the table `products` with the following structure.

`id | name | promote`

Where the column `promote` is of boolean type.

I want to set the value of the `boolean` column to `1` with the selected rows and set `0` to non-selected rows. I have the following code in the controller to handle this query.

```
$yes = Tour::whereIn('id', $request->promote)->get();
$no = Tour::whereNotIn('id', $request->promote)->get();

foreach ($yes as $item) {
    $item->promote = 1;
    $item->save();
}

foreach ($no as $item) {
    $item->promote = 0;
    $item->save();
}
```

I get following from the form request.

[image]

The above code does work but it isn't very efficient I assume. I'm looking for optional ways to achieve the result in a more efficient way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead retrieving result, looping through, you can update directly,

```
$yes =  Tour::whereIn('id', $request->promote)->update(['promote' => 1]);
$no =  Tour::whereNotIn('id', $request->promote)->update(['promote' => 0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about going through the Model to do the updating you can call update on the builder to update all the matched records. As this will use the builder and not the Model there will not be any model events fired:

```
// set them all to promote = 0
Tour::update(['promote' => 0]);
// or  just set the ones that need to be 0
Tour::whereNotIn('id', $request->promote)->update(['promote' => 0]);

// set the ones you want to promote = 1
Tour::whereIn('id', $request->promote)->update(['promote' => 1]);
```

Just one way to give it a go.